# Android Permissions Log

Tags: android, logging, android-permissions

Is there a way to actively track which apps are using specific permissions on Android?
I.E. Look in a log and see that app X just used Location Services or app Y just turned on WiFi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not possible in general. Your app has no particular rights to know what other apps are doing, just as those apps do not have any particular rights to know what your app does.

Comment: Even as root?  I know there's a log that gives some idea of system calls (when the wifi and gps is turned on/off and what time), but I thought that perhaps there was a way to cross correlate that with an app activity or memory space.

Comment: @Aeson: "Even as root?" -- root has little to do with it. "but I thought that perhaps there was a way to cross correlate that with an app activity or memory space" -- oh, that's entirely possible. But that has nothing really to do with permissions. There are dozens upon dozens of permissions, and few are tied to system calls that might get logged somewhere. You asked a very general question ("Is there a way to actively track which apps are using specific permissions on Android?"), which I answered.

Comment: If this question is too general, what question should I be asking without limiting the responses to a quick dead end?  I was going for general because I know topics can sometimes end quick if the question is too specific.

Comment: @Aeson: "what question should I be asking" -- I have no idea, as I do not know what your specific concerns are. But, for example, if you want to know how to log information about when apps use WiFi, ask a question about how to log information about when apps use WiFi.